# Is there a way in c++ to create a single Node class for different data structures such as a sparse matrix, doubly linked list, etc

Tags: c++, data-structures, clion, c++-templates

I am currently working on a project which requires me to create data structures by hand in C++.

I would like to know, if it is possible to create a template for this type of scenario, in which I can define all types of pointers, that is, `next`, `previous`, `below` and `above`?

I'm trying to implement the following data structures: sparse matrix, doubly linked list, priority queue and a doubly circular linked list. I think I might be doing extra work for no reason when I create the nodes that correspond to each data structure.

Maybe something like a variable amount of arguments would work? If so, which guide can I refer to when implementing the search functions, etc?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Note: [For many good reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4581301), posting links to images of code is the kiss of death for an otherwise good question.

Comment: No, at least not without severe limits on functionality.  Consider the methods that you'd want on such a class.  For a linked list, you might want "insert before" and insert after", both of which are pretty simple. For a 2-d sparse matrix, you might want "insert left", "insert right", "insert above", and "insert below", all of which require additional arguments to indicate where the new elements go with respect to other existing elements.  For a binary tree, you might want "insert left" and "insert right", both of which require additional logic to handle existing elements at those positions.

Comment: I don't see any reason for doing that as each data stucture would use only some of the pointers making the code slower and harder to understand.

Comment: It's hard to make a one-size-fits-all node structure that is also readable. My opinion is it shouldn't be necessary because the node is the least of your worries. It should be a dumb as possible. The container should do all of the heavy lifting, leaving the node to be only a few lines of code defining the member variables and sometimes a constructor to ensure complex initial state guarantees. It shouldn't need a destructor. 5-10 lines of code is not a noticeable amount of work compared to the hundreds or thousands of lines needed by the structure that manages the nodes.

Comment: *"in which i can define all type of pointers, that is, next, previous, below and above"* -- are you asking if it possible to define a single class that happens to have data members that are pointers and that are named `next`, `previous`, `below`, and `above`? That's how I read your phrasing. *I get the impression that you are taking shortcuts with your words, assuming that other people already know what you mean. I suggest writing out your requirements in detail. Especially for your own benefit.*

Comment: It's not useful or desirable to reuse node classes across multiple container classes. They are an internal implementation detail of each class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that I sometimes use:

```
struct Singly_List_Node
{
    Singly_List_Node * p_next;
};

struct Doubly_List_Node : public Singly_List_Node
{
    Doubly_List_Node * p_previous;
}
```

If you want, let's say a tree data structure, then your node can inherit from one of the above nodes.  These are just foundations, you'll have to fill in the methods for linking instances.

### Edit 1: Data in the nodes

If you like to have an all-in-one node, you could use a `template` (stencil).  The template version allows you to specify the data type in the node.  But, if you are going that route, you may want to use `std::list` instead.